# Why controller action can not read query string in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in Asp.Net MVC write this java script code in view page for create url action:

```
$("#BookName").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = '@Url.Action("Item", "Store", new {parentPartId = "PARENT_ID",UserID="USER_ID"})';
    url = url.replace("USER_ID", $("#USERID").val());
    url = url.replace("PARENT_ID", $(this).data("id"));
    alert(url); //just for debugging
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

and `alert(url); //just for debugging` show me this url:

```
http://localhost:2345/Store/Item?parentPartId=1&amp;UserID=1
```

And this is my Item action:

```
public ActionResult Item(int parentPartId,int UserID)
{
    StoreOnlineEntities1 storeOnline = new StoreOnlineEntities1();
    var query_find = (from p in storeOnline.BookDetails
                      where p.BookID == parentPartId
                      select new
                      {
                          p.BookID,
                          p.Exaplain
                      }).ToArray();

    ViewBag.Detail = query_find[0].Exaplain;
    ViewBag.BookID = query_find[0].BookID;
    ViewBag.UserID = UserID;

    return View();
}
```

but when run my app get this error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'UserID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Item(Int32, Int32)' in 'StoreProject.Controllers.StoreController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

How can i solve problem?thanks.

Comment: `&amp;`? That's html encoding, why is it present in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
`window.location.href = encodeURI(url);`

Comment: try this manually first `window.location.href = 'http://localhost:2345/Store/Item?parentPartId=1&UserID=1'`

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code for create URL :

```js
$("#BookName").click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var loc = window.location;
var pathName = loc.pathname.substring(0, loc.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
// to show it in an alert window
var fullUrl = loc.href.substring(0, loc.href.length - ((loc.pathname + loc.search + loc.hash).length - pathName.length)) + "Item";
window.location = fullUrl + "?parentPartId =" + $(this).data("id")+"&UserID="+$("#USERID").val();
//you can use window.location.href as well
});
```

Action should be :

```css
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Item(int? parentPartId,int? UserID)
{
```